# Count a specific letter in String

Tags: javascript, regex

Is regex possible to calculate and to count a specific character in a string?

For instance the string value "asdfasdfasdf" and you want to count how many "a" in the value?

Tried to find a solution but I cant find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

```js
 var count = "asdfasdfasdf".match(/a/g).length;
 alert(count);
```